# How to prevent duplicate posts with wp_insert_post?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to prevent duplicate posts with `wp_insert_post` on single.php?

My code is

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_title' => 'Test Shop1',
  'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum'
) );

$post_type = 'shop';
$query = "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}posts SET post_type='".$post_type."' WHERE id='".$post_id."' LIMIT 1";
GLOBAL $wpdb; 
$wpdb->query($query);
```

But every time i refresh it will added duplicate post..How will i prevent this?please help

Comment: Use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/ to check if it exists first, like `if (!post_exists('Test Shop1')) { ... wp_insert_post ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$post_title = 'Test Shop1';
if (!post_exists($post_title)) { // Determine if a post exists based on title, content, and date
    $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_title' => $post_title,
        'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum'
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and solve it with header and die functions!
after insert post, redirect to current page and die.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_arg);
if (!is_wp_error($post_id)) {
    header("Location: https://example.com/current-dir/");
    die();
}
```